# cocos2d V3 PhysicsCollision body fall into another

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I make two CCNodes, use cocos2d v3.   
 
The node A  is  static physics, node B is dynamic. 
And B's anchorPoint is ccp(0,0)
when B falls down and collisions with A , I found b's position.y is lower than A's position.y
It seems to be caught in the middle  in a very short moment.
How can it does not fall into one, but also can meet the physical effect in normal collision?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can not do that. Collision detection is defined in CS as the intersection of objects. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection)

Collision detection is a tricky problem with complex objects, so best to stick with `Chipmunk` to handle that for you.

Physics calculations run in an "update loop" kind of fashion.

You can tweak you `CCPhysicsNode` with the following properties.

```
/**
 *  The number of solver iterations the underlying physics engine should run.
 *  This allows you to tune the performance and quality of the physics.
 *  Low numbers will improve performance, but make the physics spongy or rubbery.
 *  High numbers will use more CPU time, but make the physics look more solid.
 *  The default value is 10.
 */
@property(nonatomic, assign) int iterations;

/**
 *  Physics bodies fall asleep when a group of them move slowly for longer than the threshold.
 *  Sleeping bodies use minimal CPU resources and wake automatically when a collision happens.
 *  Defaults to 0.5 seconds.
 */
@property(nonatomic, assign) CCTime sleepTimeThreshold;
```

I think you should check out the graph of `SpriteKit` to get a general idea of how the update loop and physics simulation happen in these sorts of systems.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html